# YouTube background streaming Android framework level

Tags: android, youtube, background, frameworks, video-streaming

I am trying to run YouTube video in background by giving an option of background streaming in notification panel.

Scenario What needed:

Open YouTube Application on your device click on Background Stream the applications view is collapsed and video runs in background as audio. And when Background stream is disabled then YouTube application relaunches and video starts from the same point as audio.

Approach trying :

I tried creating Virtual Display and rendering content of video on top of that, Increasing pixel of virtual display and moving it out of display area. I am getting black screen in display when i enable virtual display. And Its not helping the cause.

Kindly suggest me what I can try on android framework level or using switching application to achieve the desired scenario.

This feature is already available in many android smartphones.

i am able to achieve background stream via web view and casting but for that i need to include separate application to play.

Comment: well, there is an app, which can do this, its Youtube Premium... making an app with background playing is against YT service policy

Comment: Himanshu, the flags for the virtual display from Display Manager and the permissions you need are highly important for such use cases. Consider checking out Media Projection. Also, please share some logs